# Run a PHP MYSQL select query without the need to load a webpage

Tags: php, mysql

This is a bit of an odd one and I am not sure if it is even possible. However, what I am trying to do is develop a system for use by pilots where in which they will submit and estimated flight time/time of return. I then want to be able to run a command which will look at the current time and compare it to the time they put in and if it has exceeded that time by more than half an hour send a text notification.

I know how to do the SELECT statement and compare the times and send the text message. My issue however is getting this command to run without the need for someone to load/refresh a page on the site that this program runs off.

Is there a way to get this SELECT command and the events thereafter to run without the need for someone to constantly monitor a web page and load/refresh it. I do not want the page open at all.

Thanks

Comment: You need to take a look into Javascript (Ajax especially). See this for example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: yes - ajax (long polling), server sent events, websockets to name but three.

Comment: As far as I can understand AJAX still requires a trigger to work such as a page load or a text input. However correct me if I am wrong

Comment: So for example if I was to say SELECT flight_number FROM `flights` WHERE `time`<DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE); I am still struggling to understand how long polling would run without a page load. I apologise, I am only relatively new to working with this sort of thing.

Comment: ok - so this is to have no webpage and no user - period! Is that correct?

Comment: @RamRaider That is correct. Basically after they have entered their time of arrival I want it to be able to check every couple of minutes by itself if they are past that time and have not returned

Comment: Looks more and more like you need to write a PHP CLI script and run it through CRON every few minutes. Actually is does not actually need to be a PHP CLI, you could write it in anything

Comment: sounds like youre looking at cron jobs, or if the web-page is going to be open, run ajax requests in a setInterval()

Comment: When the pilots submit the estimated time, you probably run a bit of php and sql to store that in the database. The piece of code you are asking about can be included in the code capturing the pilots' submission.